Limit of diverging sequences.
I have a confusion in my mind. Consider two sequences of real numbers  $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$. Define $z_n: = x_n -y_n$. Suppose $x_n, y_n$ are two diverging sequences.
Then what can be said about the limit of  $z_n$?
Can I say that we can split this into two cases:
Case 1. $x_\infty = y_\infty = z_\infty = +\infty$
Case 2. $x_\infty = y_\infty = +\infty$ and $z_\infty$ is finite.
Is it? Please help.

Following your idea, there should be 3 cases for each of $x_n,y_n,z_n$, that is $+\infty,-\infty$ and finite. The 2 cases are right, but more cases should be considered.

You can say nothing about limit of $z_n$:

Let $x_n=y_n=n$, clearly they diverge, however $z_n=n-n=0$ converges to $0$.

Let $x_n=n,y_n=-n$, once again they diverge. And $z_n=n-(-n)=2n$ diverges.



Thanks for your answer.  I have made two remarks of $z_\infty$.  Am I right?

Added in the first sentence, also note that sequence may also diverge to $-\infty$

Technically there is no need to consider cases for this argument whatsoever: for any sequence which diverges but is arbitrary otherwise, say $x_n$, define $y_n:=x_n$ which diverges, so  then $z_n=x_n-y_n=x_n-x_n=0$ which converges , and similarly , defining $y_n:=-x_n$ which diverges, so $z_n=2x_n$, which diverges. Thus, no need to consider cases: , this is a general result which is true of any diverging sequence that you cannot tell if $z_n$ converges or not.
